# Merge (full join) recursively one data.table with each group of another data.table

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have 2 data.tables:

```
a.id <- c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","c")
b.id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,3,4,5)
x <- seq(1:9)
dt1 <- data.table(a.id,b.id,x)
```

and

```
rp <- c("r","s")
t <- rep(rp, each=5)
b.id <- rep(1:5, 2)
y <- sample.int(50, 10)
dt2 <- data.table(t, b.id, y)
```

For each `a.id` of `dt1`, I would like to full-join each `t` of `dt2`, adding them by column into `dt1` and giving to the column the name the value of `t`. As this is a full-join, all the missing `x(b.id)` in `dt1` are added with `NA`.

Here is the desired output (for r and s, these are random values):

```
 a.id    b.id    x     r     s
 a       1       1     14    40
 a       2       2     42    25
 a       3       3     32    11
 a       4       NA    33    3
 a       5       NA    21    1
 b       1       NA    14    40
 b       2       NA    42    25
 b       3       NA    32    11
 b       4       4     33    3
 b       5       5     21    1
 c       1       6     14    40
 c       2       NA    42    25
 c       3       7     32    11
 c       4       8     33    3
 c       5       9     21    1
```

I have tried something like:

```
dt1[, merge(.SD, dt2, by = "b.id", all = TRUE), by = a.id]
```

But it does not work.

I would appreciate your help on that problem. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try with `split` ie.. `lapply(split(dt1, dt1$a.id), function(x) merge(x, dt2, by = "b.id", all = TRUE))`

Comment: please use `set.seed` if you are going to use `sample()`.

Comment: thanks @akrun. this gives a fast solution. however, we keep t as 1 column and we get NAs for the a.id. But this is not a huge issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a cross join one can do:

```
dcast(dt2, b.id~t, value.var = "y")[
  dt1[CJ(a.id=a.id, b.id=b.id, unique=TRUE), on=.(a.id, b.id)], on="b.id"]
```

if not all possible values of `b.id` are in `dt1$b.id` then the `CJ()`-part should look like
`CJ(a.id=a.id, b.id=dt2$b.id, unique=TRUE)`
Here is another variant:

```
dt1[dcast(dt2, b.id~t, value.var = "y")[
  CJ(a.id=dt1$a.id, b.id=dt2$b.id, unique=TRUE), on=.(b.id)], on=.(a.id, b.id)]
#     a.id b.id  x  r  s
#  1:    a    1  1 46 24
#  2:    a    2  2 50 33
#  3:    a    3  3 14  6
#  4:    a    4 NA 40 28
#  5:    a    5 NA 30 29
#  6:    b    1 NA 46 24
#  7:    b    2 NA 50 33
#  8:    b    3 NA 14  6
#  9:    b    4  4 40 28
# 10:    b    5  5 30 29
# 11:    c    1  6 46 24
# 12:    c    2 NA 50 33
# 13:    c    3  7 14  6
# 14:    c    4  8 40 28
# 15:    c    5  9 30 29
```

#### data:

```
library("data.table")
set.seed(42)
dt1 <- data.table(a.id=rep(c("a", "b", "c"), c(3,2,4)), b.id=c(1:5,1,3,4,5), x=1:9)
dt2 <- data.table(t=rep(c("r","s"), each=5), b.id=1:5, y=sample.int(50, 10))
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
f<-dcast(dt2,b.id~t)
dt1[f[rep(1:nrow(f),uniqueN(dt1$a.id)),
    c(.SD,list(a.id=rep(unique(dt1$a.id),each=nrow(f))))],on=c("a.id","b.id")]
#    a.id b.id  x  r  s
# 1:    a    1  1 40 28
# 2:    a    2  2  4 17
# 3:    a    3  3 11 13
# 4:    a    4 NA 49 42
# 5:    a    5 NA 29 37
# 6:    b    1 NA 40 28
# 7:    b    2 NA  4 17
# 8:    b    3 NA 11 13
# 9:    b    4  4 49 42
#10:    b    5  5 29 37
#11:    c    1  6 40 28
#12:    c    2 NA  4 17
#13:    c    3  7 11 13
#14:    c    4  8 49 42
#15:    c    5  9 29 37
```

The result differs since a `seed` had not been set.